# Delete certain character based on the preceding or succeeding character - ORACLE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have used `REPLACE` function in order to delete email addresses from hundreds of records. However, as it is known, the semicolon is the separator, usually between each email address and anther. The problem is, there are a lot of semicolons left randomly.

**For example:** the field:

```
123@hotmail.com;456@yahoo.com;789@gmail.com;xyz@msn.com
```

Let's say that after I deleted two email addresses, the field content became like:

`;456@yahoo.com;789@gmail.com;`

I need to clean these fields from these extra undesired semicolons to be like

`456@yahoo.com;789@gmail.com`

For double semicolons I have used `REPLACE` as well by replacing each `;;` with `;`

Is there anyway to delete any semicolon that is not preceded or following by any character?

Comment: Do You want to remove all the email address from a record like 'ABC,wsds,email1@y.com;email2@y.com;email3@y.com' should be replaced with 'ABC,wsds' or you want only one email id from among multiple email ids. Think will be better if you can provide a complete example of the requirement.

Comment: @vishad I have updated my example and showed the source and the current result in addition to the desired result

Comment: Don't use REPLACE to convert multiple semicolons with one. That would convert the string 'a;;;;b' to 'a;;b' only. You see you would need a loop to reduce all duplicate semicolons. Use regexp_replace instead. See my answer below.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I do not see your answer!

Comment: No? I answered an hour ago. Don't you see three answers; one by Frank Schmitt, one by San, one by me? Try F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to replace semicolons at the start or end of the string, using a regular expression with the anchor '^' (beginning of string) / '$' (end of string) should achieve what you want:

```
with v_data as (
  select '123@hotmail.com;456@yahoo.com;789@gmail.com;xyz@msn.com' value 
     from dual union all
  select ';456@yahoo.com;789@gmail.com;' value from dual
)
select 
  value,
  regexp_replace(regexp_replace(value, '^;', ''), ';$', '') as normalized_value
from v_data
```

If you also need to replace stray semicolons from the middle of the string, you'll probably need regexes with lookahead/lookbehind.

Comment: It is rather ineffective to use egexp_replace (even twice!) when you only want to remove a particular character from front and end. You should use TRIM for that.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner True - if there are no additional requirements (like also removing stray semicolons from the middle of the string or removing whitespace before/after the stray semicolons), regexes are overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You remove leading and trailing characters with TRIM:

```
select trim(both ';' from ';456@yahoo.com;;;789@gmail.com;') from dual;
```

To replace multiple characters with only one occurrence use REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
select regexp_replace(';456@yahoo.com;;;789@gmail.com;', ';+', ';') from dual;
```

Both methods combined:

```
select regexp_replace( trim(both ';' from ';456@yahoo.com;;;789@gmail.com;'), ';+', ';' ) from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

regular expression replace can help

```
select regexp_replace('123@hotmail.com;456@yahoo.com;;456@yahoo.com;;789@gmail.com', 
                      '456@yahoo.com(;)+') as result from dual;
```

Output:

```
|                        RESULT |
|-------------------------------|
| 123@hotmail.com;789@gmail.com |
```

Comment: This doesn't adress the question - the OP wants to remove stray semicolons *after* removing E-Mail adresses from the list.

Comment: But if used to delete email addresses form the list using this query, the scenario of having stray semicolons will never arise.